# python : How to do version compare when version has ~ in it

Tags: python

I am trying to write logic to compare versions for my application in Ubuntu. The versions are generally in this format **"1.2.3~18.04"** (with a ~ followed by OS version). I used LooseVersion to compare the versions till now. But with LooseVersion being removed in python 3.11+, I was experimenting with packaging module (as advised [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/#migration-advice)). But the packaging parse() considers it as an InvalidVersion. I could do get the sub-string of version before ~ and compare this, but I am curious to know if there is a way to achieve this without the string splitting. Below is the sample code which I tried. Please advise what is the correct way to do version compares in this case.

```
from packaging import version
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

def compare_versions(version1, version2):
    if version.parse(version1) < version.parse(version2):
        return f"{version1} is older than {version2}"
    elif version.parse(version1) > version.parse(version2):
        return f"{version1} is newer than {version2}"
    else:
        return f"{version1} is the same as {version2}"

def compare_versions_loose(version1, version2):
    if LooseVersion(version1) < LooseVersion(version2):
        return f"{version1} is older than {version2}"
    elif LooseVersion(version1) > LooseVersion(version2):
        return f"{version1} is newer than {version2}"
    else:        
        return f"{version1} is the same as {version2}"

v1 = "1.2.3"
v2 = "1.2.4"
v3 = "1.2.34~18.04"

#This works as expected. output is "1.2.3 is older than 1.2.4"
result = compare_versions(v1, v2)
print(result)

#This works as expected. output is "1.2.4 is older than 1.2.34~18.04"
result = compare_versions_loose(v2, v3)
print(result)

# this throws error. packaging.version.InvalidVersion: Invalid version: '1.2.34~18.04'
result = compare_versions(v1, v3)
print(result)
```

Comment: Just use `v.split('~')[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from packaging import version
import re

def preprocess_version(version_string):
    # Remove everything after and including the "~" character
    return version_string.split("~")[0]

def compare_versions(version1, version2):
    version1 = preprocess_version(version1)
    version2 = preprocess_version(version2)

    if version.parse(version1) < version.parse(version2):
        return f"{version1} is older than {version2}"
    elif version.parse(version1) > version.parse(version2):
        return f"{version1} is newer than {version2}"
    else:
        return f"{version1} is the same as {version2}"

v1 = "1.2.3"
v2 = "1.2.4"
v3 = "1.2.34~18.04"

result = compare_versions(v1, v2)
print(result)  

result = compare_versions(v2, v3)
print(result)  

result = compare_versions(v1, v3)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
1.2.3 is older than 1.2.4
1.2.4 is older than 1.2.34
1.2.3 is older than 1.2.34
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this works as i mentioned in the summary. Just was curious to know if there is an out-of-box solution as in ubuntu osVersion is generally appended to package versions.